# Geoserver Link to External MS-Access Database

Tags: geoserver, web-mapping, database, ms-access, hyperlink

Is there a way that I can link a shape (as a polygon, with a LINK_ID = 12345) from Geoserver and have it open or link to the specific information (LINK_ID_DB = 12345) within an online Web Microsoft Access Database (on the same webserver) as a new tab to show addional information that is not in the GIS layer within Geoserver? This would enable me to update data externally for users that do not want to view the GIS data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

GeoServer does not have the ability to link to separate data sources for you, but often database products come with the ability to link external tables, you should probably look into that, and have the database in question act as the data source for GeoServer